# Need only year from date from oracle table to c#.net textbox

Tags: c#, oracle

I need to extract only year from oracle date to c#.net textbox? I'm getting year-month-date-hours-minutes-seconds. I need to select only year >1950 and < 2025.

here is  my code.

```
var yearOfGraduation = graduationDate.Year;

if (yearOfGraduation < 1950 && yearOfGraduation > 2025)
{
    lblMessage.Text = "Graduation date should be greater than 1950 and less than 2025";
    return;
}
```

on yearOfGraduation I am getting year-month-date-hours-minutes-seconds, so not able to check conditions of year between 1950 and 2025.

Comment: Well what is the type of `graduationDate`? And what do you mean by "I'm getting"?

Comment: why don't you return the date from your Oracle Query like this 
`to_char(GraduationDate, 'YYYY')` can you show the query that you are running in Oracle..?

Comment: @MethodMan - why extract the year as a string, when Oracle has extract (year from GraduationDate)?

Answer (score 1):

if you have DateTime object instance than use

```
yearOfGraduation.Year;
```

> it will only return the year part of the date

Answer (score 0):

I don't see where you are extracting the date from Oracle; anyway, if dt is a date and you just need the year, the SQL expression is

```
extract (year from dt)
```

Good luck!